# Altering a class member within a method?

Tags: java, android, object, reference

Okay this is definitely a n00b question but here goes.

The way I understand it, is objects in Java are passed by value, not reference. How then do you alter a class member within a method by passing a reference to it to the method?

I know it is possible to do, because the method getRotationMatrix does it... ie if I write the following at the class level:

```
private float rotationMatrix[] = new float[9];
```

and then within a method I call:

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, inclinationMatrix, gData, mData);
```

It will alter rotationMatrix. My question is how does that method change what is in the object I passed it if everything is passed by value?

The reason I ask is I am trying to write a method that does the same thing, but keep running into the pass-by-value conundrum. I'm trying to initialize a FloatBuffer by passing a reference to it to a method.

Comment: You have it backwards.  Objects in Java are always passed by reference, and primitives are always passed by value.

Comment: References to the object are passed by value... that's why swaps don't work when you pass them to methods, even if you are trying to swap objects. http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html

Comment: @Joey +1 for the accuracy and the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes objects are passed by value. But the Object is a reference so a copy of reference is passed. Using the reference you can modify the object but changing the reference will not have any effect on caller.

For example:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
modifyList(list);
noOp(list);

void modifyList(List l)
{
   l.add("A"); // A is added to list
}

void noOp(List l)
{
   l = null; // No effect to list, you are modifying local variable l.
}
```

Comment: So, if I have this method:

    private void initBuffer(float[] data, FloatBuffer buffer)
        {
  buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
  buffer.put(data);
  buffer.position(0);
 }

It won't actually change the FloatBuffer I pass it... how would I correctly do this?

Comment: Sorry, I formatted the code but it still scrunched it all together when I posted the comment...

Comment: @Joey there are many options: 1. You could have your method return new  buffer and assign it to required field. I.e myBuffer = yourMethodThatCreatesNewBuffer(...). 2. You could add the method to modify the FloatBuffer in FloatBuffer itself  i.e myBuffer.reallocate(...)

Comment: Thanks, I settled for the first way, since I don't think FloatBuffers themselves have a way of allocating byte order, hence why you have to make it a ByteBuffer first and cast it to a FloatBuffer...

Answer (score 0):

Java objects are passed by reference. You may be confusing references with primitives, which are always passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are dealing with objects in java, then do understand there are two things. first one is object and second one is reference to object.

So, when you pass a reference of an object to a method, then reference itself is passed by value i.e. a new reference is created in your method same to the passed one. But do mind here that though the reference is copied but the object is in place which can be manipulated by this new reference.

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, inclinationMatrix, gData, mData);
```

in your example, getRotationMatrix() method is given a new rotationMatrix reference. But by this reference none can stop you from manipulating the actual Array object.